# Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/raicesd3/public_html/openbiblio/install/index.php on line 22

Tags: php, mysql

pertenezco a una organización comunitaria y estamos intentando usar openbiblio para una biblioteca comunitaria y gratuita. Hemos tenido problemas con el cógido y no sabemos mucho de estas cosas. Al intentar instalar nos arroja ese problema. Aquí está el código.

````
  // 0.7: CircQuery uses PHP to determine current time, other scripts use MySQL
  $mysql_date = implode(mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query('select sysdate();')));
  $php_date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
  if ($php_date != $mysql_date) {
?>
    <font class="error">Mismatch in date and time configuration.</font><br>
    Recommended: correct before proceeding, else Check Out and Check In might fail temporarily.<br>
    Current date and time (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS):<br>
    <pre>
      MySQL : <?php echo $mysql_date; ?>

      PHP   : <?php echo $php_date." | date.timezone = ".ini_get('date.timezone'); ?>
    </pre>```

La línea en partícular a la que se refiere el error es:

    $mysql_date = implode(mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query('select sysdate();')));

Gracias de antemano.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uups, muchas de las instrucciones mysqli...... requieren un primer parámetro que se obtiene de la conexión con la base de datos y luego la instrucción que va a ejecutar!
ejemplo basico:
`//Conectar a la base de datos $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db, $database); //CONSULTA A LA BASE DE DATOS $accion_nm="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE columna1='algo'"; $consulta_nm=mysqli_query($conexion,$accion_nm);`

- Obvio que las variables deben estar correctamente inicializadas!